# Regex to grab a string present between (comma or whitespace) and fixed string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want a string between (comma or whitespace) and a string.

The code I am using is

```
re.findall('[,]?[\s]*(.*?)[.]calc', string)
```

The output I get on running this

```
String 1 = "Select ID, Deliveryid.calc"
Result = Deliveryid
String 2 = "Select Deliveryid.calc"
Result = Select Deliveryid.calc
```

Now For string two I just want the Deliveryid and not the hole.
Basically I want the string before ".calc" and "whitespace or comma".
It can be anyone or both in the case of comma and whitespace

There can be a newline or tab also. Basically any type of whitespace along with the comma. Both can be present or anyone.

**FYI - I want all the matching strings in the string. there can be one or many**

Comment: Do you mean `[ .]([^ .]*)\.calc` / `[\s.]([^\s.]*)\.calc` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hsHIat/1))? Or simply `[\s.](\w+)\.calc`?

Comment: The problem is with what space or comma to start matching from or what `(.*?)` can match. Please clarify these points.

Comment: Well, yes, I used a `.` instead of a `,` in the above comment. Still, the question remains.

Comment: Their can be newline or tab also. Basically any type of whitespace along with the comma @WiktorStribiżew. Both can be present or any one.

Comment: Where? Please edit the question to make it clear. Is the answer below solving the issue?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it doesn't answer my problem as there can be multiple matches, and I want all the matching substring.

Comment: Please still [edit] to show a good example of an input string with multiple occurrences, and the expected output for that.

Comment: So if `[\s,]([^\s,]*)\.calc` enough? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hsHIat/2).

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[\s,]([^\s,]*)\.calc
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hsHIat/2). Details:

- `[\s,]` - a whitespace or comma
- `([^\s,]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than whitespace and comma
- `\.calc` - a `.calc` string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HIAETV):

```py
import re
text = 'Select ID, Deliveryid.calc Select ID, Deliveryid.calc Select ID, Deliveryid.calc\nSelect Deliveryid.calc Select Deliveryid.calc'
print( re.findall(r'[\s,]([^\s,]*)\.calc', text) )
# => ['Deliveryid', 'Deliveryid', 'Deliveryid', 'Deliveryid', 'Deliveryid']
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the regex slightly

```
import re
String1 = "Select ID, Deliveryid.calc"
String2 = "Select Deliveryid.calc"
m1 = re.search('[, ]([^, ]*?)[.]calc', String2)
print ('->' + m1.group(0) + '<-')
print ('->' + m1.group(1) + '<-')
```

I think you should get value of group(1).

Comment: Why findall is not working as I am getting \t\n while using findall but when using match it gives the correct answer. And how to get the list and not the object while using match?

Comment: And there can be multiple matching strings in that. So how get the list for all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use greedy regex operators.
try this:

> `^[^.]+`

It will match everything before the dot
Note: that when using greedy operators, you'll match everything before the last .(dot) instead of the first.
As per your string it matches everything before the .calc

[image]

If you want only a word before .(dot) then "Wiktor Stribiżew" has already helped you out for that. His expression works for me similar way.
[image]

Happy Learning !!